# E_ALL doesn't report parse error?

Tags: php

I am not getting any error message in browser due to curly brace missing at the end of if.

What should i use in error_reporting setting?

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$a = 1;

if($a == 1){
echo $a;

?>
```

Comment: You should get an unexpected PHP end, but there's nothing to set other than what you've done afaik. Are you in a shared host environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parsing failed, so PHP newer executed a line of code.

Put those settings in `php.ini`.

Answer (score 3):

When PHP execute the `ini_set('display_errors')` instruction the parser phase is already done.
You have to change this option by *.htaccess*, *virtual host* or *php.ini*

[How to change configuration settings on PHP.net site](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php)

Answer (score 2):

I use this statement in `.htaccess`:

```
php_value error_reporting 32767
```

See [this](http://perishablepress.com/advanced-php-error-handling-via-htaccess/) for details.

For me, this is convenient because I use the Zend framework, and only need one htaccess file in the `public` folder that controls everything.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot catch parsing errors.
The best thing to do is fix your syntax.